# How to add a legend to an ecdf plot?

Tags: r

I am generating an ecdf plot and would like to add a legend to it, but getting the following error:

```
plot(xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,1), main=NULL, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", 
     ecdf(PrecentageVector1),  col="red", do.p = FALSE, pch=19, 
     lwd=3,  legend("bottomleft",c("A","B","C")), panel.first = grid()) 

Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) :  
invalid graphics state
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't recognize the error and can't reproduce it because you didn't give us `PrecentageVector1` (sic). In general, try calling `legend()` after `plot()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?legend` is a function all on its own, it is not a part of the `plot` call.
As @timriffe says, you would need to do something like:

```
PrecentageVector1 <- c(10,20,30)
plot(xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,1), main=NULL, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", 
     ecdf(PrecentageVector1),  col="red", do.p = FALSE, pch=19, 
     lwd=3, panel.first = grid()) 
legend("bottomleft",c("A","B","C"))
```

Comment: `panel.first = grid()` looks suspicious.  Do you know if that is actually used by `plot.ecdf` (etc)?

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - I thought so too and hadn't seen it before, but it works! Try `plot(1:10,panel.first=grid())` There is also `panel.last=` - `plot(1:10,panel.first=grid(),panel.last=abline(v=4,col="red"),pch=19)` See `?plot.default`

Comment: Thanks, yes I see now.  I had to flip back and forth between adding and not adding the argument to see the difference.  The grid lines are very feint on my monitor.  Seemed to do nothing at first, so I thought the argument was sucked into a `...` somewhere along the way.

Comment: And now that you mention it, `panel.last=legend(`...`)` works for the questioner.  As does `panel.first={grid(); legend(`...`)}`.  Ain't base fun.  I think I'll stick with lattice.